# $E$ is open iff union of open balls

Tags: proof-writing, metric-spaces

Let $(A, d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq E \subset A$ a subset. Define $B(a) = \{b \in A : d(a, b) < \epsilon\}$. Show that $E$ is open $\iff$ it can be written as the union of a family of open balls of the form $B(a)$ above.

I have a general proof for an open set involving the union of balls:

> Theorem: If $(A, d)$ is a metric, then $E \subset A$ is open $\iff$ it is the union of open balls.

> Suppose $E$ is open then by definition; for every $x \in E$, there is some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset E$. A claim: $E = \bigcup_{x\in E} B(x,r)$. Choose $x \in E$ then can find $r>0$ such that $x \in B(x,r) \subseteq \bigcup B(x,r)$. Suppose, by a converse argument, $y \in \bigcup B(x,r) \implies y \in B(x,r) $ for some $x$. But $B(x,r) \subseteq E$ for some $x$ so $y \in E$. So $E$ is the union of open balls.
> Going the other way, suppose $E = \bigcup_{\phi} O_{\phi} $ where $O_{\phi}$ is open ball. Take $x \in E$, then $x \in O_{\phi} $ for some $\phi$. But $O_{\phi} \subseteq \bigcup O_{\phi} = E$. So, we have found an open ball inside $E$, and $E$ must be an open set.

> QED.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to do the problem with the specific form $B(a)$. Can somebody show me how to do this problem? Any hints or assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Thematically this looks OK. I might work on the notation a bit, e.g., make slightly clearer that for each $x$ your set $B(x,r)$ is being fixed (for example, $r$ varies from place to place although this is not a material part of the argument). If you look at the argument as currently drafted, the letter $r$ is a little bit overloaded. It depends on a choice of $x$, it's also something you can find after choosing $x$, etc. Complicating the notation may simplify the argument.

Comment: @leslietownes How would I do the problem at the top though?

Comment: The notation $B(a)$ takes the radius $\epsilon$ as some kind of implicit parameter. Your argument using the notation $B(x, r)$ to make both the centre and the radius explicit is correct.The problem you are trying to solve has been very badly expressed.

Comment: @RobArthan So does the theorem suffice as a proof for the problem given?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your original problem (stated at the top), $a$ is a fixed point (if it is not fixed then I don't understand what $B(a)$ is supposed to denote):

The theorem is clearly wrong.

Counterexample:

Let the metric space be $\mathbb{R}$ and let $E = (1,2) \cup (3,4)$. $E$ is clearly open however, it cannot be union of family of open balls of form $B(a)$ since such a union must be a open segment centered at $a$.

This is probably not what you meant, so maybe you can edit the question to make it clear.